# Best way to fill a roster schedule

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Fellow programmers,

I got a roster application build in PHP with the framework : Laravel. And i have the following issue:

My application has : Users, Taskdate's, and TaskdateTime. Each user can get a TaskdateTime assigned to them. That TaskdateTime is a child of Taskdate. I want to populate a schedule where each user can see all their times. The schedule looks like this :

[image]

What i do in my application is : Fetch all users, Fetch all Taskdate's and according to the Taskdate's, fetch the TaskdateTime's for the right Taskdate. I do this in the following way :

```
$taskdates = Taskdate::with('users')->where_date($date)->get();
$employees = Usergroup::with(array('users', 'users.workdates'))->where('usergroup_title', '=', 'Employees')->first();
```

You can see that i fetch usergroups, with the relationship : Users and with the User->workdates relationship. Where the workdates returns the TaskdateTime objects as mentioned above.

Now in my view, i do this to populate it with data. And this seems like a lot of extra hassle and i think it could me much easier but i can't wrap my head around it. Anyway, this is the code :

```
<table id="plan" class="table table-bordered">

    <thead>
        <th></th>
        @foreach($taskdates as $taskdate)
            <th id="{{ $taskdate->id }}">{{ $taskdate->subject }}</th>
        @endforeach
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($employees as $employee)
            <tr id="{{ $employee->id }}">
                <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>

                 @foreach($taskdates as $taskdate)

                    <?php
                    $result = array_filter($employee->workdates, function($user) use ($taskdate){
                         return $user->id === $taskdate->id;
                    });
                    ?>

                    @if( empty($result) )
                        <td></td>
                    @else
                        <td id="{{$result[key($result)]->pivot->id }}" style="{{ ($result[key($result)]->pivot->taskdate_isread) ? '' : 'font-weight:bold;'}}">
                            {{date('H:i', strtotime($result[key($result)]->pivot->taskdate_time))}}
                        </td>
                    @endif


                 @endforeach  

            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So i am filtering the whole workdates relationship of each user, if its hold the Taskdate id. And if it is empty, then don't echo anything.

The syntax of the HTML/PHP is in BLADE, so it might not seem correct PHP parsing, but it is.

**Edit :**

Question :

My code feels bloated. I don't think this is the most efficient way to achieve the result. What is your opinion on this? I like to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: what is your question? does the code work?

Comment: Yes, the code works. But it feels bloated. And i wonder if this is the most efficient way of doing this.